# evaluation summation Erlang distribution

Tags: probability, summation

I have to calculate a renewal function: $H(t)$. 
In which: 
$$ 
H(t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-e^{-\lambda t}\sum_{i=0}^{2n-1}\frac{(\lambda t)^i}{i!}\right)
$$
I think it can be solved by switching $n$ and $i$ in the summations, however I am not sure...

Comment: This is equivalent to evaluating $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=2n}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}~$

Comment: The value of the latter is $~\dfrac{(3+2x)~e^x+e^{-x}}4~$

Comment: If the lower summation limit for *k* would have been *n* instead of *2n*, we'd have $S=(x+1)~e^x.$

Comment: And if the lower summation limit for *k* would have been $3n$ instead of $2n$, for $x=1$ we'd have $$S=e+\dfrac{3\cos\dfrac{\sqrt3}2+\sqrt3\sin\dfrac{\sqrt3}2}{9\sqrt e}$$

Comment: And for *k* starting at $4n$ and $x=1$ we have $S=e+\dfrac{\cos1+\sin1-\sinh1}4$